# How to filter markers on a Gmaps object with angular and javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

The purpose of this code is to display markers on a gmap but have them filtered based on dates. Hence only the markers created during the selected time will be shown.

I'm watching a value coming from from an external js script called `obj.dateRangeSlider("values")`.

as seen below;

```
//this will watch the value coming from the time slider and update $scope.filteredMarks accordingly. This could also be expanded to include the search bar.
$scope.$watch(function () {
    //function returning the value to watch, aka dates selected
    return obj.dateRangeSlider("values");
}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    //function to do when the value changes
    $scope.filteredMarks = $filter("filter")($scope.marks, function(value, index){
        //filter function to recreate the $scope.filteredMarks with the reduced data
        //this is called for each element of $scope.marks
        if(value.date >= newValue.min && value.date <= newValue.max){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is then displayed on the webpage as follows;

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' ng-init="lat = 'observation_latitude'">

    <ui-gmap-markers models="filteredMarks" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" fit="true">
    </ui-gmap-markers>

</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

However im getting this error multiple times;

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3…return%20m%3Da%7D%3B%20newVal%3A%20%5B%5D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%5B%5D%22%5D%5D
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:56499/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:6:450
    at k.$digest (http://localhost:56499/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:110:38)
    at k.$apply (http://localhost:56499/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:112:173)
    at h (http://localhost:56499/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:72:454)
    at w (http://localhost:56499/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:77:347)
    at XMLHttpRequest.z.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:56499/Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js:78:420)
```

Return from `$scope.marks`:

```
>     [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
>     
>     0: Object   
>     date: "2014-11-30T23:21:44.823Z"  
>     id: 11  
>     latitude: -27.46009230397052
>     longitude: 153.0309266845481  
>     __proto__:  Object  
>     Object1:  
>     Object2:  
>     Object3:  
>     __proto__: Array[0]
```

I'm pretty lost as to the cause of this and would love a clue. I can provide more information if someone thinks it will help.

Cheers Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your error is coming from

`return obj.dateRangeSlider("values");`

Instead of running obj.dateRangeSlider() inside the watch, take it outside, and return the variable with the object saved in it. More details can be seen [**here**](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=undefined).
Hope this gave you some good idea.